# New comments after a user's last comment

Tags: php, sql

Edit: I've added everything I can...

I have the following query, which gets the last comment from the user in a given topic, then I check in the while loop if there are newer comments.

My problem is, that the while loop runs through every thread the user commented (imagine a user commented 2000 times, then this runs 2000 times).

Can I simplify it somehow to run only if there's a newer comment?
**EDIT: I can, added answer below, but new query is slow.**

With the current database setup probably not, but maybe I'm missing something.

In my comment database I have columns like date (comment date), user_id, topic_id (and picture_id and news_id ehich is the id of the given topic, pciture or news) and seen (which is a datetime and it gets updated when the user checks the given thread).

E.g.:

```
id (1) date (2018-12-02 10:00:00), topic_id (3), user_id (3), text (comment text...), seen (2018-12-02 10:00:00)


id (2) date (2018-12-04 15:30:00), topic_id (3), user_id (5), text (comment text...), seen (2018-12-04 15:30:00)
```

User 3 goes back to the thread on 12-05 12:00, so seen gets updated from 2018-12-02 10:00:00 to 2018-12-05 12:00:00).

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `picture_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `news_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_vote` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_hit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `moderated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seen` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `ip` text COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_hungarian_ci;
```

---

#### PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT p1.* FROM comment p1 INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT max(date) MaxPostDate, user_id 
           FROM comment WHERE user_id='$me' and deleted=0 
           GROUP BY topic_id, picture_id, news_id) p2 
        ON p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND p1.date = p2.MaxPostDate 
        WHERE p1.user_id='$me' and deleted=0 
        ORDER BY p1.date DESC "
$comment_query = sql_query($conn, $sql);
if(sql_num($comment_query)!=0)
{
while ($comment = sql_fetch($comment_query))
{
```

Here's some more code, if you need it for some reason:

```
    if($comment['topic_id']!=0)
    {
        $current_forum = sql_fetch(sql_query($conn, "SELECT url, name
        FROM forum
        WHERE id='".$comment['topic_id']."' and deleted=0"));
        $current_comments = sql_fetch(sql_query($conn, "SELECT count(id) as count, date 
        FROM comment 
        WHERE deleted=0 and topic_id='".$comment['topic_id']."'"));
        $comment_topic_id = $comment['topic_id'];
        $comment_id = $comment['id'];
        $comment2_query = sql_fetch(sql_query($conn,"SELECT count(id) AS cid 
        FROM comment 
        WHERE topic_id=".$comment_topic_id ." and id<".$comment_id ." and deleted=0 "));
        $result = $comment2_query['cid'] + 1;
        if($comment['seen']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            $unread = $current_comments[0] - $result;
            if($unread!=0)
            {
                if((!empty($_GET['p'])) and $_GET['p']=='forum' and 
                $_GET['x']==$current_forum['url'])
                //If I'm at the specific url (I'm watching the new comments, so update it)
                {
                    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    sql_query($conn,"UPDATE comment SET seen='$now' WHERE user_id='$me' AND id='$comment_id' AND topic_id='.$comment_topic_id.' ");
                }
                else //increase number to add it to noficiation bell
                {
                    $count++;
                    $forum_notif++;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $last_time_seen = $comment['seen'];
            $count_comments = sql_fetch(sql_query($conn,"SELECT count(id) AS cid
            FROM comment 
            WHERE topic_id=".$comment_topic_id." and deleted=0 and date>'.$last_time_seen.' "));
            if($count_comments['cid']!=0)
            {
                if((!empty($_GET['p'])) and $_GET['p']=='forum' and 
                $_GET['x']==$current_forum['url'])
                {

                    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    sql_query($conn,"UPDATE comment SET seen='$now' WHERE user_id='$me' AND id='$comment_id' AND topic_id='.$comment_topic_id.' ");
                }
                else
                {
                    $count++;
                    $forum_notif++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($comment['picture_id']!=0)
    {
       //same code again for a different type of forum (only topic_id is replaced to picture_id and the links)...
    }
    elseif($comment['news_id']!=0)
    {
       //same code again for a different type of forum (only topic_id is replaced to new_id and the links)...
    }
  }
} //This is the whole code
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but the query is really slow (on first time, it's obviously quick when coming from cache).
This new query is great, it does exactly what I want finally (get only the comments after a user commented), but unfortunately it's slow (~2 sec), when not cached.

```
$sql = "SELECT p1.* FROM comment p1 INNER JOIN
          (SELECT max(seen) last_seen, max(id) MaxId,
          user_id, topic_id, picture_id, news_id, date
          FROM comment WHERE user_id='$me' and deleted=0
          GROUP BY topic_id, picture_id, news_id) p2
       ON p1.topic_id = p2.topic_id and p1.picture_id= p2.picture_id
       and p1.news_id= p2.news_id
       WHERE p1.date > p2.last_seen and p1.id > p2.MaxId and deleted=0
       GROUP BY p1.topic_id, p1.picture_id, p1.news_id ORDER BY p1.date DESC"
```

The original query was this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT p1.* FROM comment p1 INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT max(date) MaxPostDate, user_id 
       FROM comment WHERE user_id='$me' and deleted=0 
       GROUP BY topic_id, picture_id, news_id) p2 
    ON p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND p1.date = p2.MaxPostDate 
    WHERE p1.user_id='$me' and deleted=0 
    ORDER BY p1.date DESC"
```